# building a web proxy to a desktop application using .net

Tags: asp.net, .net

We have a regular .Net4 desktop application built using WPF that exposes a handful of methods via WCF as Net.tcp and also WSHTTP as a rest interface for some simple remote control and remote querying. This is so we can provide some easy 'dashboards' that keep track of what each of the applications is doing around an organisation. We have used MVVM patterns wherever possible with future expansion in mind.

We now need to build a web application for users to do some remote work. Most of this work will be done by the web interface itself directly accessing the SQL database and other resources and rendering HTML back to the end user.

We also want the users of this web application to be able view these dashboards for certain specified desktops, at which point we need to then have the Web application query the desktop applications for the answers.

In due course it's likely that we will expand this further to expose REST or SignalR based or similar to support a Xamarin based set of apps.

My current theory is that we will build this web application using ASP.Net and host on IIS and whenever the user needs to access a resource that requires connecting to the desktops we spin up a WCF connection to the REST services running on it, send the query, process the result and return it onwards to the user.

Is this the best way to go about it, or is there some sort of native web service "proxy" that we can utilise to transparently forward the request from the website user onto the desktop?

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to host a web server in a desktop application? Will the network actually allow that? Why don't you let the desktop applications push their data to the web service, and let the web service store that data somewhere, so it's available for all web service consumers without having to connect to the specific desktop application instance?

Comment: I've edited the question slightly - the web server would be hosted in iis and to the majority of the workloads to do with data requests etc, but the onwards connection to the desktop based applications is because those applications so a lot of real world hardware interactions and we need to allow remote users to directly trigger features on those desktops - there is a realtime need so we can't wait for the desktop to observe a notification via a db and then respond, it needs to be direct - does that help explain a bit further?

Comment: Yeah in that case I'd indeed look at some bidirectional principle like SignalR.